# Ruby libXML Xpath find returns result in result

Tags: ruby, xpath, erb, libxml2

Parsing a XML document with Ruby libXML i noticed a strange behaviour.
When searching for some elements and traversing the result, I get the result object back in the result itself.

Here's an example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
    <projects>
        <project id="1">
            <name>Project 1</name>
            <van>Guus</van>
        </project>
        <project id="2">
            <name>Project 2</name>
            <van>Guus</van>
        </project>
    </projects>
</main>
```

Parsing the code (controller):

```
 @projects = @xmlDoc.find('//project[@id]/name')
```

Displaying it (view):

```
<ul>
<%= @projects.each do |pr| %>
    <li><%= pr.first.content %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<hr>
<%= @projects.inspect%>
```

Results in:

```
- Project 1
- Project 2
  #<LibXML::XML::XPath::Object:0x000008153182c0>  
------------------------------------------------------------------------
#<LibXML::XML::XPath::Object:0x000008153182c0>
```

As you can see, the list contains the XPath object self.
I intentionally displayed it as a bullet list and an inspect after a horizontal line.
As you can see, the last item does not have a bullet in front of it.
But where does it come from?
Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value for [`each`](http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/XPath/Object.html#method-i-each) is the result object itself. In your code, since you use `=` in the line `<%= @projects.each do |pr| %>`, you print out each of the projects as a list item (in the block), *and then print the return value from `each`*.

The solution is just to use `<% ... %>` (i.e. no `=`):

```
<ul>
<% @projects.each do |pr| %>
    <li><%= pr.first.content %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```